# Typescript: prevent assignment of object with more properties than is specified in target interface

Tags: typescript

Say I have a typical 'user' object with the usual username, email, password, etc. properties. I want to create and manage an object that is a bona fide 'subset' of such a user with assurances that the password is NOT included. Here's a rough approach:

```
interface IUserSansPassword {
    username: string;
    email: string;
}

class UserSansPassword implements IUserSansPassword { ... }

interface IUser extends IUserSansPassword {
    password: string;
}

class User implements IUser { ... }
```

In trying to create an object of type `IUserSansPassword`, I expected the following to error:

```
const userSansPassword: UserSansPassword = new User(); // No TS Error †††
```

However, I don't get a TS error because, to my surprise, TS doesn't prohibit assigning objects with already established 'extra' properties. This is surprising since I would get an error if I tried to define directly with the extra property like so:

```
const userSansPassword: IUserSansPassword = {
    username: 'jake',
    email: 'jake@snake.com',
    password: '' // TS Error ***
}
```

My questions in summary:

1. Why does TS behave this way? Isn't it bad to allow assignment to a type with excess properties (hence why you get an error in *** above)?
2. Is there a TS setting or technique I can employ to get TS to error in ††† above?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The other answers here are essentially correct: types in TypeScript are generally open/extendable and can always have properties added; that is, they are not *exact types* (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)) in which only known properties are allowed to exist.  TypeScript doesn't really support exact types in general, although it does treat the types of freshly created object literals as exact types via [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks), as you've noticed.

If you really want to forbid a particular property key from a type in TypeScript, you can do this by making the property optional and have its type be `never` or `undefined`:

```
interface IUserSansPassword {
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password?: never; // cannot have a password
}

declare class UserSansPassword implements IUserSansPassword {
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password?: never; // need to declare this also
}
```

Now `UserSansPassword` is known *not* to have a defined `password` property.  Of course now the following is an error:

```
interface IUser extends IUserSansPassword { // error! 
// Types of property "password" are incompatible
  password: string;
}
```

You can't extend `IUserSansPassword` by adding a password... if `A extends B` then you can always use an `A` instance where a `B` instance is expected.  What you can do is extend a related type, your original `IUserSansPassword`, which can be computed using the [`Omit` helper type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#the-omit-helper-type):

```
interface IUser extends Omit<IUserSansPassword, "password"> {
  password: string;
}

declare class User implements IUser {
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
```

And then the following is an error like you expect:

```
const userSansPassword: UserSansPassword = new User();
// error, mismatch on "password" prop
```

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFUDO0DKcSYAKcmmA7gPZQAmyA3gFDLICu2UIcAthAFzKYwUUAHMA3E2QQucYABt+g4SHGSADiXJVqAfn4gIAN2hjkAejPIE+EBTDIAFnGPI4yDaUo0GAXwYNqCAQ5OCgUYM1kLFx8Ik0vWmAuNTlpCHBMNGioPAJiT216STZoTh5FIVEJZmlZBQFKlWr3eO09ZANjKFMLDogIWjAKZECIsOQwB2BMuDlMCl9-UEhYRBQMdikAD0gQakyAeS5gMAAeDZi81poAGmQAIg8tGnuAPiLmJ4SK5VU-AKCIXGEVIUU2SRSaQyWU2jGYJQ43D4DV+zVq8h+VXU12omKaiwYCAoBHsCNycQKNH42XJ+WetAAvH0yGDoAAKACUEl60CgVDux0wMjACAcyGJDy+2nu7j5agYQA)

Comment: Great explanation and suggested solution. Thanks!

Comment: See also: nominative typing vs structural typing.

Comment: should that `password?: never` to be `password?: void`, so only allow `undefined`?

Comment: @Moon... no, as I mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72794638/2887218#comment128577521_72794638)... `undefined` and `void` are not the same type, and you hardly ever want to use `void`.  Perhaps you mean `password?: undefined` instead, but this is not necessary.  With `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` disabled, it is just redundant.  With it enabled, it means that you want to allow *explicit* setting of `undefined`, which is usually not what people mean.  `password?: never` is the right thing for almost all use cases.

Comment: If you can demonstrate, with a [mre], a situation in which `password?: void` is preferable to `password?: never`, I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 0):

If `UserWithPassword` is a subtype of `UserWithoutPasword`, any OOP language allows the assignment. The only TypeScript difference - you shouldn't explicitly implement the interface. TS only checks that the shape of the object meets the interface type.

Another case - the object literal initialization, excess properties are not allowed here. The compiler expects that the created object shape should exactly match the type of the variable, the object will be assigned to. It's rather a mistake to create an object and immediately lose a part of its type after the assignment.

Comment: This is generally correct, except the `User` class clearly doesn't extend `UserSansPassword` in the question.