# Typescript - assign unallowed indexed field

Tags: typescript

I have this little Typescript code and would like to understand why it is not giving me a type error:

```js
interface Test {
    name: string;
}

const someString: string = 'someString';

const test: Test = {
    name: 'Foo',
    [someString]: 'Bar' // <- why is this not an error?
};
```

The interface Test is not defining an index field, yet I can set the field. If I directly set a string value instead of using a variable, I get a type error:

```js
interface Test {
    name: string;
}

const test: Test = {
    name: 'Foo',
    ['someString']: 'Bar' // I get a type error here as expected
};
```

Comment: I think this answer is relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/57499679/7133623

Comment: I think you are right, it probably has to with excess property checks.

Comment: The difference between the two code examples (one errors, one doesnt) is that in one case you are passing a generic `string` key (`[someString]: 'Bar'`). In the other case the key is the `'someString'` literal, (`['someString']: 'Bar'` which is the same as just `someString: 'Bar'`