# Typescript should I use void or never on the optional object type property

Tags: typescript

I have defined a type, `T1` and `T2`. The purpose of this the union type of these two is when you have `a` in the object, you cannot have `b`, and when you have `b` in the object, you cannot have `a`, like the below.

```
type T1 = {
    a?: void,
    b: string,
}

type T2 = {
    a: string,
    b?: void,
}

type TAllowed = T1 | T2

const t1: TAllowed = {
    a: 'abc'
}

const t2: TAllowed = {
    b: 'bcd'
}
```

My question is with the optional object property type, should I use `void` or `never`. I tested with `never`, like `a?: never` and it's same result too. However, `a?` means a could be undefined, it could return something.

If I use never on the property, I have

```
type T1 = {
    a?: never,
    b: string,
}

type T2 = {
    a: string,
    b?: never,
}
```

Both `void` and `never` accept `undefined` value:

```
const t1: TAllowed = {
    a: 'abc',
    b: undefined // b can have a `undefined` even it's never
}

const t2: TAllowed = {
    b: 'bcd',
    a: undefined
}
```

So I'm not sure if we can use `x?:never`. Basicly, `never` means no value, but here it accepts `undefined`.

So what's the correct type here, `void` or `never`?

Comment: Why should these 2 types know about each other

Comment: For example, with a function, I want the accepted parameters are when I pass A, I cannot pass B and When I pass B, I cannot pass A. That's why this `TAllowed` here.

Comment: The type `void` generally means "this is a useless value you shouldn't look at" while the type `never` means "this is impossible".  If you're trying to say that `TAllowed` either has a defined `a` or a defined `b` but not both, you should use `never` instead of `void` because `void` is not guaranteed to be undefined; it could be any value in practice, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/w8EQEN).  I'm confused why you would think to use `void` here, though.

Comment: but `?` means optional, this means both a and b accept `undefined`, even though I set their type is `never`.

Comment: What does that have to do with `void`?  `undefined` and `void` are not the same type.  If you are asking about the difference between "present but `undefined`" and "missing", TypeScript doesn't model that well unless you enable [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes), which is not part of the `--strict` suite because it's a bit too pedantic for many situations.  But again, this doesn't seem to have anything to do with `void`.

Comment: @DanielA.White https://effectivetypescript.com/2021/11/11/optional-never/