# Why literal object keys are not being inferred?

Tags: typescript

Given the following code,

```
function define<T>(asset: T): T {
  return asset
}

const assets = define({
  header: { color: 'red' },
  button: { color: 'red' },
})

assets.header.color // works, no errors expected
assets.button.color // works, no errors expected
assets.footer.color // works, it reports an error b/c `footer` is not at the assets object.
```

However, if I explicitly specify a schema for the values of my keys, TypeScript no longer understands the keys of my object as literals, but instead as mere `string`s:

```
function define<S, T = Record<string, S>>(asset: T): T {
  return asset
}

const assets = define<{ color: string }>({
  header: { color: 'red' },
  button: { color: 'red' },
})

assets.header.color // works, no errors expected
assets.button.color // works, no errors expected
assets.footer.color // does not work, an error was expected but was not thrown
```

Questions:

1. Why is this happening? Why `assets.footer.color` does not report an error?
2. Is there a fix? If so, how?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: TypeScript doesn't have partial type parameter inference as requested in [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) so that `T` just falls back to `Record<string, S>`.  If you want to simulate that you'll need currying like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w231VN).  Does that address your question? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: You answered my question, indeed! I was suspicious that it could be a TypeScript quirk, and you have just clarified that. You went beyond, actually - you gave me a practical solution for the problem as well! So thank you for your input and make it an answer so I can accept it. :-)

Comment: I just noticed a problem, though - the schema is not being respected; I can set a `color` to my object and TypeScript does not complain. [See here, line 19](https://tsplay.dev/NBR1DN).

Comment: "I can set a `color`" doesn't make any sense to me, sorry. Are you not trying to use a `color`?  Am I going crazy here?

Comment: @jcalz Typo, doh! Sorry. I meant I can set any excess key not specified by my schema `<S>` and TypeScript won't complain. It only complains if my object doesn't satisfy at least the keys specified in the schema. On line 19, there's a `test: 123` key-value that demonstrates what I'm talking about.

Comment: Well, just read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57497299/typescript-prevent-assignment-of-object-with-more-properties-than-is-specified). Nevermind my last comment. Feel free to go ahead and make your first comment an answer and I'll gladly accept it. :)

Comment: Yeah, excess properties are their own thing.  You can try [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mpLzbm) maybe?  I've answered partial-type-parameter-inference questions multiple times before so I've linked to those questions instead of writing up a separate answer here.  Upvoted this question, though, fwiw.