# Is it possible to omit any property that has specified substring?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create an interface that accepts any object as generic. In create method it should accept the object matching the generic type but with any property that has "id" as substring to be omitted. So the problem is that different interfaces might have property "id" in different shapes like: **id**, _**id**, __**id**, entity**id** and so on. So I would like to have something like:

```js
interface IBaseRepository<T extends object> {
  create(input: OmitAnyPropertyWithSpecifiedSubstring<T, 'id'>): Promise<T>;
}
```

Is it possible to implement it? If yes, how?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wQ251N) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining (but probably tomorrow because I'm going to bed now); otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, yea, thanks, it looks like what I need, you can leave it as answer

Comment: @jcalz What does the `K in keyof T as K` expression do in the mapped type? I see that if the `as K` is removed there's an error about a circular reference, but I don't understand how `as K` resolves that—it seems like it just renames it to what it was already named.

Comment: @Jimmy, that expression remaps the K key to K extends Something? ifTrueA : ifFalseB. So that way we can verify whether the property name extends what we need, and after the check we set remapped value either ifTrueA or ifFalseB. Check this out: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as

Comment: Ah, thank you. I misinterpreted the precedence. I read it as `(K in keyof T as K) extends \`${string}${S}${string}\` ? never : K` but it's `K in keyof T as (K extends \`${string}${S}${string}\` ? never : K)`.

Comment: What if you have keys like `didDoSomething`, `pid`, or `video`? You'll get errors because those all have "id" in them but they could be plain fields.

Comment: @vera. My playground link above has `middle` excluded, and OP is apparently happy with it. ‍♂️

Comment: @jcalz, hmm, actually I forgot to think about the case vera mentioned. I am not happy about that case

Comment: @vera., I guess as a workaround we can come up to stick something between id substring in property names like di_dDoSomething, pi_d, vi_deo. But it is 100% ugly workaround

Comment: So what should we do here? I could write up my answer and mention that the compiler is just looking for substrings no matter where they appear and cannot tell the difference between an intentional and an unintentional instance of the sunstring (such as in the middle of another word)

Comment: @jcalz, I think we can leave it as an intermediate solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [key remapping with `as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to convert undesirable keys to `never`, which has the effect of excluding the property from the mapped type.  The pattern [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) `` `${string}${S}${string}` `` will match any string where `S` appears as a substring (as long as `S` is some specific string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types)), so you can use [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) to suppress any keys assignable to that type:

```
type OmitAnyPropertyWithSpecifiedSubstring<T extends object, S extends string> =
    { [K in keyof T as Exclude<K, `${string}${S}${string}`>]: T[K] }
```

Let's test it out:

```
interface Foo {
    prop: number,
    entityid: string,
    id: number,
    _id: string,
    idiosyncraticPropertyName: boolean,
    appearsInTheMiddle: number,
    hardToAvoid: string
    otherProp: string
}

type OFoo = OmitAnyPropertyWithSpecifiedSubstring<Foo, "id">;
/* type OFoo = {
    prop: number;
    otherProp: string;
} */
```

Notice that only `prop` and `otherProp` survive, because all other properties contain the substring `"id"`.  You are apparently not happy with something like `"hardToAvoid"` or `"inTheMiddle"` being suppressed, because you didn't *intend* for them to contain `"id"`. ‍♂️  I'm not sure how you want to handle that, but I'm going to say that it's firmly outside the scope of the question as asked and move on.

---

Let's make sure it works with your example:

```
interface IBaseRepository<T extends object> {
    create(input: OmitAnyPropertyWithSpecifiedSubstring<T, 'id'>): Promise<T>;
}

declare const x: IBaseRepository<Foo>;
x.create({ prop: 1, otherProp: "abc", entityid: "oops" });
// error! --------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'entityid' 
// does not exist in type 'OmitAnyPropertyWithSpecifiedSubstring<Foo, "id">'
```

Looks good.  The compiler complains about `entityid` because of [excess property checking on object literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks), as desired.

Do note though that excess properties are not generally invalid, and so if you use an intermediate variable you will likely not get a warning... this is intended behavior of TypeScript and you can read more about it at [Typescript: prevent assignment of object with more properties than is specified in target interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57497299/2887218)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=9&noErrorTruncation=true#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-X9--8Ad+MrXjAChKMAUDBEgAw+MEUBwD4ICyKgwRIew2Y0EhLioDgADuqBQAuNz0OwagfAwUBFvuoCllAwFQAwOAQDIOEQWICBds4iqUcmzJptcBDsqQXLUHQub8gWQobmKBhFkAA)