# What's the difference between an optional field and a union?

Tags: typescript

Is there any practical difference between:

```
{
    ok: boolean;
} | {
    ok: boolean;
    error: any;
}
```

and:

```
{
    ok: boolean;
    error?: any;
}
```

I've noticed the difference in the inferred types of frontend methods' return values, both methods doing things like:

```
try {
  const response = await axios.post(url)
  return response.data as Payloads[Endpoints.EndpointName]
} catch (error) {
  return { ok: false, error }
}
```

where one `Payloads[Endpoints.EndpointName]` is:

```
{
    ok: boolean,
    error?: any,
}
```

and another is just:

```
{
    ok: boolean,
}
```

I expect both return values to behave the same, but as they are not the same formally, I wonder if I should be aware of some quirks. The only difference that I can think of is that the union type allows using `Exclude` (and generally the helpers for unions). Anything else?

Comment: Seems pointless to have the union without a _discriminant_: `{ ok: true } | { ok: false, error: any }`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe pointless or not, this is what TypeScript has inferred for the return value, it's not what I assert it to. Also, it's not yet what you've proposed, currently it can return `{ ok: false }`

Comment: The main difference is that union type doesn't always allow you to use the `error` property, whereas the optional one does, and union types can be narrowed while non-union types are generally not narrowed.  See [this demonstration](https://tsplay.dev/NBBjbN).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, ah, right, that and the differences with IDE autosuggestions actually cover the question, thanks for reminding and feel free to put this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript will not let you index into an [object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types) with a key unless that key is known to exist in the type.  This is largely responsible for the observable differences between `{ok: boolean} | {ok: boolean, error: any}` and `{ok: boolean; error?: any}`.

There are usually further differences between [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) and required properties, involving how [`undefined`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined) is treated, but since your property type is [the catch-all `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), that distinction is largely gone.

---

The type `{ok: boolean}` isn't known to have an `error` property, so if you try to index into it with an `error` key, the compiler will complain. That doesn't mean a value of type `{ok: boolean}` cannot *have* an `error` property;  object types in TypeScript are not sealed (see [Typescript: prevent assignment of object with more properties than is specified in target interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57497299/2887218) for more information).  As such, the type `{ok: boolean}` by itself is similar to `{ok: boolean; error?: any}` already. But it is considered a mistake to index into an object type with a key that is not known to exist.

Furthermore, if you have a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of object types, you can only index into it with a key known to exist in *every* member of the union.  So `{ok: boolean} | {ok: boolean; error: any}` still won't let you index into it with the `error` key, since the first union member doesn't know about `error`:

```
type T = { ok: boolean; } | { ok: boolean; error: any; }
declare const c: T;
c.error = {} // error
```

On the other hand, `{ok: boolean; error?: any}` does know about the `error` property, so you are allowed to index into it.

```
type T = { ok: boolean; error?: any; }
declare const c: T;
c.error = {} // okay
```

IntelliSense will only suggest keys known to exist, so you will also see the difference in suggested keys.

---

Furthermore, a union of objects with non-union properties is conceptually similar to a non-union object with union properties, but they are not considered equivalent in TypeScript.  Your example types aren't exactly this, since `any` washes out the distinction, but it's close.  Compare `{a: string} | {a: number}` to `{a: string | number}`.

The major difference is that unions can be directly [narrowed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) via various type guards, whereas non-union objects generally don't get narrowed this way.

So, for example, if you [assign](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) a value to a variable of a union type, the compiler will narrow the apparent type of that variable to just the relevant union member(s).  Depending on what value you assign, you can get different subsequent behavior upon accessing the variable:

```
// union behavior
type T = { ok: boolean; } | { ok: boolean; error: any; }
const a: T = { ok: true }
a.error // error
const b: T = { ok: true, error: {} }
b.error // okay

// non-union behavior
type T = { ok: boolean; error?: any; }
const a: T = { ok: true }
a.error // okay
const b: T = { ok: true, error: {} }
b.error // okay
```

So while `a` displays the same distinction between union and non-union types, `b`in the union case is narrowed to `{ok: boolean; error: any}`, so that suddenly behaves much as if you were using the non-union type (the only difference between them is that `error` is optional in one and required in the other, but that distinction doesn't do much).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBVYBLA9sJBvAUEkgC4CeMyAKkgLx5KYDWAXEgEaaYA2EIwA3EgC+SAD70mrDt14CkEAE4LMC1n1KChhJPGxRiSEK2p1cDFiQUBXZFqIgAdIuUKkAejfylK7buD72Y1oJC2JrCAAaLxdWXBE7didvVw9zEFJtABMIeC4QBWQ-APhjfl8kl2C4909nFSJ8LXxQSFgEZAB5GGIsUC48bTIKJBMQqU4ePkE6hQB+NWANYV89AyMRqvNWMJtl+wr61KZ0lf8DNiDTLcsbKJnY+O02A5TPY4yibNz8wtWdUvKMyqIiOjBOQiAA)